# Oracle query not returning results when a value is missing

Tags: sql, oracle

So i have query which checks a value pair for couple of values in a table and returns a result. 
Sample query:

```
SELECT NVL(IR16, 'N/A') AS CODE,
NVL(IR15, 'N/A') AS AMOUNT
from table a, table b
where a.pk = b.pk and and regexp_substr(ir16,'\d+$') = regexp_substr( ir15,'\d+$')
```

returns a result set for example

```
-codea   1
-codeb   2
-codec   3
```

But if the value pair is missing, it will just not return the row. for example the codec is there but value 3 does not exist, it will just return

```
-codea   1
-codeb   2
```

I want the query to return codec N/A, if a value is missing. 
Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN`, so you can get all the codes

```
SELECT NVL(IR16, 'N/A') AS CODE,
NVL(IR15, 'N/A') AS AMOUNT
from table a
LEFT JOIN table b
ON a.pk = b.pk 
and regexp_substr(ir16,'\d+$') = regexp_substr( ir15,'\d+$')
```

Comment: does it work the same way with multiple tables? i am getting a ORA-00905: missing keyword
eror

Comment: @Sandy, can you paste data in sql fiddle to look at the error

Comment: it is asking me to import the schema in it before it. the thing is i am using a web app to run the queries on

Comment: i can give u the whole query i am using, i just gave you a sample for it

Comment: there are multiple tables involved in it, and they all join to 1st table

Comment: @Sandy, yes you can have left join with other tables too

Comment: i used this from section:  FROM   invoice i2
       LEFT JOIN invoice_refnum ir16
       LEFT JOIN invoice_refnum ir15
       LEFT JOIN invoice_refnum ir17
       LEFT JOIN invoice_refnum ir18     LEFT JOIN invoice_refnum ir19

Comment: ir16 is column in your original query, but here you are using the same as table alias name. is there column called ir16 in your table that you need to do regex and compare?

Comment: hmm i am trying to paste the query here, but its too long. that column was ir6.abc something, but i just shortened it for example. can we attach documents here?

Comment: @sandy, then you need to do same in the regex use ir16.abc

Comment: smaller version:SELECT distinct IR16.invoice_refnum_value AS GL_CODE1, 
       IR15.invoice_refnum_value AS GL_AMOUNT1 
FROM   invoice i2 left join invoice_refnum ir16
       left join invoice_refnum ir15
       
WHERE  i2.invoice_gid = ir16.invoice_gid 
       AND ir15.invoice_refnum_qual_gid like 'NOV/RIQ.GL AMOUNT%' 
       AND i2.invoice_gid = ir15.invoice_gid 
       AND ir16.invoice_refnum_qual_gid like 'NOV/RIQ.GL CODE%' 
       AND i2.invoice_gid = 'NOV/RIQ.20141104-0084'
and regexp_substr(ir16.invoice_refnum_qual_gid,'\d+$') = regexp_substr( ir15.invoice_refnum_qual_gid,'\d+$')

Comment: @sandy, take out where and use ON clause .SELECT distinct IR16.invoice_refnum_value AS GL_CODE1, IR15.invoice_refnum_value AS GL_AMOUNT1 FROM invoice i2 left join invoice_refnum ir16
on i2.invoice_gid = ir16.invoice_gid
left join invoice_refnum ir15 ON ir15.invoice_refnum_qual_gid like 'NOV/RIQ.GL AMOUNT%' AND i2.invoice_gid = ir15.invoice_gid AND ir16.invoice_refnum_qual_gid like 'NOV/RIQ.GL CODE%' AND i2.invoice_gid = 'NOV/RIQ.20141104-0084' and regexp_substr(ir16.invoice_refnum_qual_gid,'\d+$') = regexp_substr( ir15.invoice_refnum_qual_gid,'\d+$')

Comment: i tired doing this, strangely it is giving me all rows an results and is not honoring: AND ir15.invoice_refnum_qual_gid LIKE 'NOV/RIQ.GL AMOUNT%' 
                     AND ir16.invoice_refnum_qual_gid LIKE 'NOV/RIQ.GL CODE%' 
                     AND i2.invoice_gid = 'NOV/RIQ.20141104-0084' 
                     AND Regexp_substr(ir16.invoice_refnum_qual_gid, '\d+$') = 
                     Regexp_substr(ir15.invoice_refnum_qual_gid, '\d+$')

Comment: so its acting like any of and statements dont matter, its giving all rows and columns